# Xcode 8 uploading archive failed due to asset

Tags: xcode, ios10

I'm trying to upload archive to run a test through testflight. But Xcode 8 rejected the archive with the error message `Invalid Bundle: The asset catalog at '.... path/extension.appex/Assets.car' can't contain 16-bit or P3 assets if the app supports iOS 8 or earlier`. Is this something to do with assets type I added in assets for extension? Does anyone experience similar error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried with deployment target iOS 8.2 worked for me. As per Apple "You'll need to move the target OS back to 8.2.  There have been multiple issues at play here.  The one you're seeing is that Assets.car generated with a Deployment Target of 8.3 or 8.4 incorrectly include a key that trips up the iTC validation.  This is unrelated to extensions that may or may not exist in the parent app (where there was a separate problem).

Having said that, with iOS 10 going live soon, our recommendation will be to move your Deployment Target to 9.x."

Comment: I actually was abled to upload with 9.0.

Comment: Yup, any iOS target version is good, except iOS 8.3 & iOS 8.4

Comment: +1 good answer..
it has worked for me also.

Answer (score 2):

The following command found here https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/60919 solved our issue

> find . -name "*.png" -print0 | xargs -0 identify | grep "16-bit" | awk '{print $1;}' | xargs mogrify -depth 8

Run it in the root of our git repo for Xcode project, then it will identify all 16-bit png images and modify them to 8-bit depth.

If P3 colorspace png exists, we will need another command for the identifying and converting.

Comment: Gives `xargs: identify: No such file or directory` output

Comment: you need to install imagemagick first

Comment: I installed imagemagick and still getting xargs: identify error